# HTML Mic Visualizer

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I would like to build a graphic visualizer app for my friends talent show performance, and I need to visualize some microphone input. How can I do this with html and javascript? The visualization I would like is the 'bars'

Thanks!
-Nate

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use HTML5 `AudioContext` to collect samples, analyse them, and display the results. [here](http://html5-examples.craic.com/microphone_input_with_spectrogram.html) is a working example that does something similar (but shows spectrogram on a canvas).

Comment: This demo link does not work at all with Chrome/Canary now. Would you like to check that please?

Comment: @YumYumYum: Not my page, so can't fix it, but it seems they have a typo in code, at the very least ("MonkeyPath" should be "MonkeyPatch"). A [link](http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound) from that page also looks useful.